# matlab plot legend variable

Tags: matlab, variables, legend

My question is about the legend entry of a matlab plot.

I would like to have the input variables in the legend so that it looks like 'A_1 B_2'. A,1,B and 2 are input arguments in the variables letter1, number1, letter2, number2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify any names as inputs to the legend. Your question really seems to be about how to concatenate variables into a single string. Usually, the easiest way to do this is with the `[]` operators.

```
figure()
hold on
h1 = plot(1:10)
h2 = plot(5:15)
legend([letter1,'_',num2str(number1)],...
       [letter2,'_',num2str(number2)])
```

Comment: Thanks, it works almost perfect. But not all my numbers are whole numbers, so I get for instance for A_0.5 just the 0 as index, not the whole A_{0.5}. How to do that?

Comment: Do you want the literal braces around `0.5`? I would build my string in that case using `sprintf`: `sprintf('%s_%f',letter1,number1)`. You can adjust the format specifiers if you want different appearance.

Comment: Sorry, not the literal braces. That was just TeX habit of me.

Comment: Also, the method in the answer works even for numbers that are not integers. The `sprintf` method is useful only if you want more control over exactly how your floats are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If it was the case, maybe you can just set it at the ending of the plot command and title, for instance:

```
g <- make_empty_graph() # crate a new canvas to show this example
plot(g) # just to pup up the canvas created
```

labeling:

```
legend("bottomleft", legend=c("legend1", "legend2", "legend"), lty=c(1,2,3), lwd=c(2.5,2.5,2.5), col=c("black", "burlywood4", "skyblue"))
```